# unicorn with heroku bamboo stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, webserver, unicorn

I just came across [this post](http://blog.railsonfire.com/2012/05/06/Unicorn-on-Heroku.html?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email).It just nicely explains about configuring unicorn server for rails app on heroku cedar stack.

I added unicorn in my gem file and started my server on 0.0.0.0:8080 and its working perfectly fine. I have added the unicorn.rb in my config directory as given in the post I mentioned above.How can I know in my development environment that unicorn added the workers?  Also **can I use unicorn with heroku bamboo stack?if yes How?**

I am novice to the field i.e in set & configure rails server,I am not getting any way to head forward & don't have much idea about this at all.So please suggest some resources to learn about set up & configure servers for rails applications from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bamboo stack doesn't support Procfiles which you would need to use Unicorn in production. You'd need to migrate to Cedar stack to use Unicorn on Heroku.